# How does Linkedin redirect from email to app so fast and without passing through the browser?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, html-email

I want to make a link to send it in a email so when the receptor clicks it send him directlly to the app (ios or android) if he has it installed or to the browser if he has not the app

Linkendin mails (for example) do that, but i don't know how.

Thanks a lot.

Edit: My app is an hibryd app developed with Cordova

Answer (score 1):

> Firebase Dynamic Links are links that work the way you want, on
>   multiple platforms, and whether or not your app is already installed.

Check this https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/

Comment: it sounds good, but i dont know if it is compatible with my app which an hibryd app with Cordova

Comment: @Borja Check this https://github.com/chemerisuk/cordova-plugin-firebase-dynamiclinks